# Ruby object inheritance between classes within a module

Tags: ruby

I am having a hard time finding good examples of how to have a shared instance of a Class shared between other instances within a Module.  I am not even sure if I'm describing it properly :)

Here's the general thing I'm trying to achieve:

```
module NSX
  class Manager
    def initialize(server, user, password)
      @nsx = RestClient::Resource.new(
        server,
        user: user,
        password: password)
    end
  end

  class Service
    def initialize(some_args)
      # assign instance variables, etc
    end

    def self.get(service_id)
      # USE NSX::Manager INSTANCE HERE
      obj = allocate
      response = JSON.parse(instance_of_manager[service_id].get)
      obj.send(:initialize, response)
      obj
    end

    def save
      # USE NSX::Manager INSTANCE HERE
      instance_of_manager[self.id].post(self.to_json)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to instantiate an NSX::Manager object which holds all the connection details for the service.  I want to be able to reference that instance in other NSX module classes, both as class methods and instance methods (to do an HTTP GET, or HTTP PUT, for example.)

I haven't been able to find any good examples of how to do this, or if it's even possible.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or give me some ideas on how to approach this structurally?

Thanks!

Comment: And to add a little more detail, this code would be used like this:

`service = NSX::Service.get('12345')  # this would make the API call to get an object`
`service.description = 'modified description'`
`service.save   # this would make the API call to save the object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module NSX
  class Manager
    attr_accessor :nsx

    def initialize(nsx)
      @nsx = nsx
    end
  end


  class Service
    def self.get()
      puts NSXManager.nsx
    end

    def save
      puts NSXManager.nsx
    end
  end
end
```

`Creating a constant` that can be referenced from inside the module(or from anywhere else using the proper name):

```
require_relative 'nsx'

manager = NSX::Manager.new(3)
NSX.const_set('NSXManager', manager)

NSX::Service.get
NSX::Service.new.save

--output:--
3
3
```

**Edits:** ---------------------------

```
module NSX

  class Manager
    attr_accessor :nsx

    def initialize(nsx)
      @nsx = nsx
      NSX.const_set('NSXManager', self)
    end
  end


  class Service
    def self.get()
      puts NSXManager.nsx
    end

    def save
      puts NSXManager.nsx
    end
  end
end
```

Exercise the module:

```
require_relative 'nsx'

NSX::Manager.new(3)

NSX::Service.get
NSX::Service.new.save

--output:--
3
3
```

Comment: Okay I think I follow here, but a couple questions...  What if an instance of class Manager requires some parameters (like in my example)?  Do those parameters need to be passed every time?  Can you pass them as a sort of setting to the module, which would persist for future calls on the NSX module?

Comment: Oh man, const_set looks very promising.  Can this be called from within the Manager class for the parent module?  I.E. if an NSX::Manager.new is called, it always sets the parent constant?

Comment: @geezyx, Yep, `const_set()` can be called inside `initialize()`--see the edits above.

Comment: I love you.  This has been bugging me for weeks, thank you!